# Upload model with IFormFile propertis from Angular2 to ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to send model which part is some IFormFile type propertis which represent user avatar. But unfortunely my avatar propertis is always null, i saw a lot of exampels how to send single picture element but i can find exampels how send it when it is part of model not a single element as it is done [here for example](https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/09/02/upload-file-image-angular2-aspnetcore/)

Here is my component method in which i set this props

```
  editUser(model: Company) {
this.errors = '';
debugger;
console.log(model);
let fi = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
if (fi.files) {
  let fileToUpload = fi.files[0];
  model.avatarImage = fileToUpload;
}
model.id = this.company.id;
this.companyService.update(model)
  .subscribe(
  result => {
    if (result) {
    }
  },
  errors => this.errors = errors);
```

}

Here my company model at angular2 side

```
export interface Company {
id: string,
advertiseTitle: string,
advertiseDescription: string,
city: string,
street: string,
categoryId: number,
price: number,
facebookPage: string,
instagramPage: string,
avatarImage: File
```

}

And my put methods from client side

```
    update(company: Company) {  
    return this.apiService.put(`${this.path}/${company.id}`, JSON.stringify(company));
}
```

Put method in apiService

```
put(path: string, body): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    this.setBearerHeader();
    console.log('Http Post Observable: ', path, body);
    let url = `${this.baseUrl}${path}`;
    let request = new Request({
        url: url,
        headers: this.headers,
        method: RequestMethod.Put,
        body: body
    });

    return this.http.request(request)
        .catch(this.handleError)
        .map(res => res.json())
};
```

Firs what i was thinking can be a reason was JSON.stringify but it don't change anything it always is empty in the request 
[image]

Here is my backend put method(ASP.NET Core)

```
// PUT api/values/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody] CompanyViewModel dto)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  try
  {
    if (id != dto.Id)
    {
      return BadRequest();
    }

    //var entity = _mapper.Map<Company>(dto);
    //_shopDbContext.Comapnies.Update(entity);
    Company entity =  this.Get(id);
    entity.CategoryId = dto.CategoryId;
    entity.City = dto.City;
    entity.CategoryId = dto.CategoryId;
    entity.Street = dto.Street;
    entity.Price = dto.Price;
    entity.AdvertiseTitle = dto.AdvertiseTitle;
    entity.InstagramPage = dto.InstagramPage;
    entity.FacebookPage = dto.FacebookPage;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      await dto.AvatarImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
      entity.AvatarImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    _shopDbContext.Comapnies.Update(entity);
    await _shopDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(dto);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

And here also remove [FromBody] don't change anything in this case.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I think that in this case necessary is to create two different post.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me know if you figure it out.I do not want to create 2 different post.it is almost 2019 and nobody is able to send IFormFile inside in a viewmodel?

Comment: Check this http://fiyazhasan.me/story-of-file-uploading-in-asp-net-core-part-ii-angular/  , it work for me

Comment: @Stefan did you figure it out?

Comment: @Sanam, To be honest, I do not remember it was years ago :P

Answer (score 8):

Based on  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular#answer-47597472) I manage to submit a form including an file to asp.net core Web API from Angular 5.

model on server:

```
[Required]
public string ExpenseType { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Activity { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Provider { get; set; }
[Required]
public decimal RequestedAmount { get; set; }
[Required]
public IFormFile InvoiceFile { get; set; }
public string Comment { get; set; }
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostPaybackRequest([FromForm] WellnessPayback payback)
{ 
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
    // TODO
    return Ok();
}
```

model in angular:

```
export interface IWellnessPayback {
  expenseType: string;
  otherActivity: string;
  provider: string;
  requestedAmount: number;
  invoiceFile: File;
  comment: string;
}
```

method in angular service:

```
public postPaybackRequest(payback: IWellnessPayback): Observable<boolean> {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const prop in payback) {
    if (!payback.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { continue; }
    formData.append(prop , payback[prop]);
  }
  return this._http.post<IOption[]>(`${this._baseUrl}/Me`, formData).pipe(map(x => true));
}
```

where `this._http` is an `HttpClient`.

Comment: This is the best answer for uploading image in a model. There is no any solution except this one. Thanks...

Comment: @moi_meme how did you submit rest of ur model to the api?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- Pass the image as a base64 string as described here: [Angular 2 encode image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272970/angular-2-encode-image-to-base64). The base64 string can be bound to a `byte[]` property server-side.
- Use a multipart form request as described here: [File Upload In Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular-2). The form parts can be bound server-side with an `IFormFile` or `List<IFormFile>` action parameter.

Comment: I know how to do it when i only want to send a IFormFile as single element
https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/09/02/upload-file-image-angular2-aspnetcore/
But when it is as property of my model and a try to send it as a part of body i don't know how to do it because it is always null. Can I add whole object to  let input = new FormData();? I hope that you understand me, that problem is not to send a file by send file as part of whole model.