# How to send file from angular to dotnet core controller

Tags: angular, .net-core, file-upload

I have been seen so many related questions and I have visited many of them. but none of them solved the problem as most of the solution works around stand alone logic of file uploading. while I am trying to achieve something similar to this

[Upload model with IFormFile propertis from Angular2 to ASP.NET Core WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919932/upload-model-with-iformfile-propertis-from-angular2-to-asp-net-core-webapi)

I am working with angular react form where I am submitting a data to a controller of dotnet core. Everything works fine uptil I pass file module

user.model.ts

```
export class user{

public fullName: string;
public phoneNumber: string;
// etc
//etc
public file File;

}
```

model on the server

```
public class User{

public string FullName {get; set;}

public string PhoneNumber{get; set;}

public IFormFile File {get; set;}


   }
```

End point

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserDetail(User request)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("One or more required parameters not passed.");

            var response = await _qaMetricService.AddQAMetricDetail(request);

            return Ok(response);
        }
```

File upload function in angular file

```
fileChange = (event: any) => {
    const files: FileList = event.target.files;
    //const fileList = new Array<File>();
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append(files.item(i).name, files.item(i));
      this.fileList.push(files.item(i));

      console.log(this.fileList);    //working on multiple files before

    }


  }




 OnSubmit(){

    ////All code

    userVM.file = this.fileList[0];


//calling serice 

 this._userService.addUserService(userVM).subscribe((res: APIResponse) => {

});



    }
```

it did not work.. Now most of the solutions are advising on using FormData.. How would I be able to submit entire model data using FormData at once??

pls someone help me figure out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the whole model like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fullName ', this.form.get('fullName').value);
formData.append('phoneNumber', this.form.get('phoneNumber').value);
formData.append('file', this.form.get('file').value);
this._userService.addUserService(formData).subscribe(console.log)
```

if you have multiple file you can append all the files in your formData using [] in the key:

```
files.forEach((file) => {
 formData.append('file[]' , file, file.name);
}
```