# Difference in Base64 encoding

Tags: java, angular, base64

I am trying to encode, Image to Base 64 string in AngularJS2

```
   handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];
        if (files && file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
       }
    }
_handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
       var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
       this.model.UserProfileImageBase64 = btoa(binaryString);
      console.log(this.model.UserProfileImage);     
      }
```

I am receiving a different string,in compare to encoding it from Java

```
Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap),Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Any Idea how can we match both Base64 encoding? I had tried same with base64 encoding in angular as well

```
    this.model.UserProfileImageBase64 = Base64.encode(binaryString);
```

But no dfiference in result.

BtoA and Base64 producing same result and, if I am verifying it online I am getting image as well but I need it in the same format which is generated by Java

Comment: What's the difference exactly? Please try to compare the results and provide some information where differences are (beginning, middle, end) how many.

Comment: Length of Both strings are different starting chracter of Java string (I can't post whole string)/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/  and this is Angular JS/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/4QwtRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwEyAAIAAAAUAAAAY

Comment: How much length difference? If you use a diff on the strings you should get information about how much differences are there or if they are in the middle, start, end. Posting the string isn't useful anyway.

Comment: First 27 character is same
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/ then angular  start from /4Qw and java /2w, length of java converted string is 23261 while angular is 1034274

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same result with java and javascript.

With java I did:

```
byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new URL("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"));
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
System.out.println(base64);
```

With javascript I did:

```
const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
 fileReader.onloadend = () => {
      retVal.next(fileReader.result);
 };
```

**NOTE**: I would suggest not to use readBynaryAsString as it is deprecated and might not work. [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString)

**NOTE**: That in javascript I wait till the file is uploaded to get the data and I passed to an observable *next(...)*

Comment: Can you please upload javascript code on plumcker it's going to be big help

Comment: Have a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/hqc891wPzeEgjZG49zJ1?p=preview   Let's say that this code needs to be refactorized :-) It is just a draft

Comment: the same string I am also getting but in case of IOS/Android(java)

Answer (score 0):

```
changeListener($event) : void {
  this.readThis($event.target);
}

readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
  var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();

  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    this.image = myReader.result;
  }
  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="changeListener($event)">
```

Follow this link [Angular 2 encode image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272970/angular-2-encode-image-to-base64)